# write a text in equation style in userform

Tags: excel, userform

I have a userform in which values are read from different excel sheets to text boxes in the userform. I wonder that is there any way to show the labels in the equation style like this for example:

[image]

for now, I wrote it as (X1+y)/y^2 which doesn't look nice in the userform. Do you think that it is possible to write it in the sheet and load it as an object or sth in the userform?

Answer (score 0):

You can create what you want as a **graphic** rather than **text** by using the *Equation Editor*

To access the *Editor*, click on the `Insert` tab in the Ribbon.  The *Equation Editor* will be on the far right-hand side of the Ribbon.

For information on its usage, see:

[Office Documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/write-an-equation-or-formula-1d01cabc-ceb1-458d-bc70-7f9737722702)

There is also tutorial material on YouTube.

Once created you must find a way to include the Shape on your Userform.